# Interpreting interactions in a regression model

Tags: r, regression, lm, interaction

A simple question I hope.

I have an experimental design where I measure some response (let's say blood pressure) from two groups: a control group and an affected group, where both are given three treatments: t1, t2, t3. The data are not paired in any sense.

Here is an example data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(response = c(rnorm(5,10,1),rnorm(5,10,1),rnorm(5,10,1),
                         rnorm(5,7,1),rnorm(5,5,1),rnorm(5,10,1)),
                 group = as.factor(c(rep("control",15),rep("affected",15))),
                 treatment = as.factor(rep(c(rep("t1",5),rep("t2",5),rep("t3",5)),2)))
```

What I am interested in is quantifying the effect that each treatment has on the affected group relative to the control group. How would I model this, say using an linear model (for example lm in R)?

Am I wrong thinking that:

```
lm(response ~ 0 + treatment * group, data = df)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
lm(response ~ 0 + treatment + group + treatment:group, data = df)
```

is not what I need? I think that in this model the treatment:group interaction terms are relative to the mean over all baseline group and baseline treatment measurements.

I therefore thought that this model:

```
lm(response ~ 0 + treatment:group, data = df)
```

is what I need but it's quantifying each combination of treatment and group interaction terms: treatmentt1:groupcontrol treatmentt1:groupaffected treatmentt2:groupcontrol treatmentt2:groupaffected treatmentt3:groupcontrol treatmentt3:groupaffected

So perhaps this model:

```
lm(response ~ 0 + treatment + treatment:group, data = df)
```

is the correct one?

Although in addition to quantifying each combination of treatment and groupaffected interaction term it's also quantifying the effect of each treatment. I'm not sure what is the baseline each of the treatment and groupaffected interaction terms are compared to in this model.

Help would be appreciated.

Also, let's say I ran a fourth treatment which is actually the combination of two treatments, say t1+t3, where I don't know what the expectation of their combined effect is: additive/subtractive or synergistic. Is there any way this can be combined?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly you're basically interested in 3 contrasts? You want to know what the difference is between "t1 affected" and "t1 control", between "t2 affected" and "t2 control", and lastly, between "t3 affected" and "t2 control"?

Comment: You are not really asking a programming question here, you are asking a question about statistical modeling. Therefore, you question belongs on [stats.se], not Stack Overflow.

Comment: N311V you're right. This is exactly what I'm interested in

Answer (score 3):

The interaction term tells you that the difference between groups is dependent on treatment, that is, that the difference between affected and control is not the same for t1, t2 and t3.

I would model the intercept though.

```
lm(response ~ group + treatment + group:treatment, data=df)
```

After getting a significant interaction term I would use t.tests to further investigate and to help with interpretation.

As can be seen the interaction is driven by the larger effect of t2 relative to the others.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(response = c(rnorm(5,10,1),rnorm(5,10,1),rnorm(5,10,1),rnorm(5,7,1),rnorm(5,5,1),rnorm(5,10,1)),
             group = as.factor(c(rep("control",15),rep("affected",15))),
             treatment = as.factor(rep(c(rep("t1",5),rep("t2",5),rep("t3",5)),2)))

# t tests of the desired comparisons to see if there is a difference and get 95% confidence intervals
t.test(df$response[df$treatment=="t1"] ~ df$group[df$treatment=="t1"])
t.test(df$response[df$treatment=="t2"] ~ df$group[df$treatment=="t2"])
t.test(df$response[df$treatment=="t3"] ~ df$group[df$treatment=="t3"])

# plot 95% C.I.
ci_plot <- matrix(nrow=3, ncol=3)
ci_plot <- as.data.frame(ci_plot)
colnames(ci_plot) <- c("treatment", "lci", "uci")

ci_plot[,1] <- c("t1", "t2", "t3")
ci_plot[,3] <- c(t.test(df$response[df$treatment=="t1"] ~ df$group[df$treatment=="t1"])$conf.int[1],
             t.test(df$response[df$treatment=="t2"] ~ df$group[df$treatment=="t2"])$conf.int[1],
             t.test(df$response[df$treatment=="t3"] ~ df$group[df$treatment=="t3"])$conf.int[1])
ci_plot[,4] <- c(t.test(df$response[df$treatment=="t1"] ~ df$group[df$treatment=="t1"])$conf.int[2],
             t.test(df$response[df$treatment=="t2"] ~ df$group[df$treatment=="t2"])$conf.int[2],
             t.test(df$response[df$treatment=="t3"] ~ df$group[df$treatment=="t3"])$conf.int[2])

ggplot(ci_plot, aes(x=treatment, y=uci)) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=uci, ymax=lci), width=0.5, position=position_dodge(0.9), weight=0.5) +
    xlab("Treatment") +
    ylab("Change in mean relative to control (95% C.I.)") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: good point, simple t-tests will suffice.  Though I do like my approach.  Same result, be a little less code (i.e. I call `lm` once, and you call `t.test` three times).  Nice plot!

Comment: I think that replacing a multiple regression with a series of t-tests is a general concept which is usually avoided probably mainly since in regression the variance is better estimated. Based on your suggestion what's the point in using ANOVA's if you can substitute them with t-tests?

Comment: @dan you're right. Given that you were having trouble interpreting the interactions I tried to simplify it for you. I agree with Jacob H's answer below, keep the intercept. The significant interaction term tells you that the difference between affected and control depends on the treatment. The figure above and post-hoc t.tests (which are really only used to get 95% C.I. of the change) suggests that the significant interaction is driven by the larger effect of t2 than the others. I'll try and improve my answer.

Comment: @dan the regression and t-test are equivalent in this simple example.  The advantage of the regression however, is that it is simple to introduce additional controls into the model.  Imagine that you think that a person's income will affect their response.  You can directly include income as a regressor.  Regression also makes it easy to compare numerous results at once.  Finally, regression allows you to easily accommodate non standard situations.  What if the data is heteroskedastic?  What if you're using count data?  What if your treatment is not randomly assigned but a instrument exists?

Comment: Exactly, not to mention the multiple hypothesis corrections associated with the series of t-tests. Hence my comment. I must say that the interaction terms in lm(response ~ 0 + treatment + treatment:group, data = df) give exactly the effects in your plot. Do you see anything wrong with this formulation?

Comment: I'm really not sure what `lm(response ~ 0 + treatment + treatment:group, data = df) ` is going to do. It might be fitting a model that forces both groups to have the same mean. If this gets moved to Cross Validated you'll probably get a much better response.

Answer (score 2):

Your first specification is fine.

```
lm(response ~  0 + treatment * group, data = df)

Call:
lm(formula = response ~ 0 + treatment * group, data = df)

Coefficients:
         treatmentt1               treatmentt2               treatmentt3  
               7.460                     5.081                     9.651  
        groupcontrol  treatmentt2:groupcontrol  treatmentt3:groupcontrol  
               2.670                     2.384                    -2.283
```

The first coefficient, 7.460, represents the effect that occurs when a participant is both treated with t1 and affected.  Going from left to right, the second coefficient, 5.081, represents when a participant is both treated with t2 and affected, etc...

So for example, when a participant is treated with t2 and in the control the effect is 5.081 + 2.384.

If I were doing this analysis, I would keep the intercept.

```
Call:
lm(formula = response ~ treatment * group, data = df)

Coefficients:
         (Intercept)               treatmentt2               treatmentt3  
               7.460                    -2.378                     2.192  
        groupcontrol  treatmentt2:groupcontrol  treatmentt3:groupcontrol  
               2.670                     2.384                    -2.283
```

Now the second coefficient, going from left to right, represents the effect of participants treated with t2 and affected relative to participants treated with t1 and affected.  To see this notice that 7.460 - 2.378 = 5.081 (the second coefficient in the first specification).  I like this approach because it makes it easier to interpret the relative effects.

That all being said @MrFlick is right.  This is a question for Cross Validation.